# python-form not displayed using show method

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am working with python plugins for QGIS.I have my main form as **DlgQueryBuilder.py** and another form as **DlgDberror.py**,which displays the error in the query.My **DlgDberror.py**
contains following:

```
class DlgDbError(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_DlgDbError):
def __init__(self,e,parent):


    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
    Ui_DlgDbError.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)
    msg = "<pre>" + e.msg.replace('<','&lt;') + "</pre>"


    self.txtMessage.setHtml(msg)



@staticmethod
def showError(e, parent):

    dlg = DlgDbError(e,parent)
    dlg.show()
```

The call to this from **DlgQueryBuilder.py** is  "**DlgDbError.showError(e, self)**" 
Everything goes smooth but when i try to run my main form **DlgQueryBuilder.py**,**DlgDberror.py** form is not shown.It dissapears within a second.
dlg.show() should work rite??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `showError` exits, `dlg` is garbage collected and goes away which also destroys the underlying Qt objects and the dialog.  I suspect you need to pass your dialog back to QGIS in some way so it can handle whatever is necessary with the dialog.  So yes, `show()` works, but your program is destroying the dialog before it can do anything useful.

Perhaps you wanted `exec_()` instead?  It will pop up the dialog and then block waiting for the user to close the dialog.  This is known as a modal dialog.  See http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdialog.html

Comment: if i use dlg.exec_() then it gives error saying TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable...

Comment: Oh, sure.  I somehow figured you were trying to show a dialog.  Looks like you've built a QWidget instead.  Did you mean to inherit from QDialog?  Are you following the docs at http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/plugins.html#plugins for creating a plugin?